# Passing the results of top into a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

**Problem**: I want to create a service which can clean up another service that only runs when the node and target pod is not under heavy load on a kubernetes cluster.

**Solution**: Unsure, I want to try and do something that involves passing the values of `kubetctl top` into a pod so it can decide what to do based on current load.

Is this possible or is there another solution?

Edit: I've been asked for more clarification. The pod in question will be an eventstore instance and want to run the scavange (clean up ) when CPU usage is low to prevent the clean up slowing the pod down. I want to make a piece of code that can query the load and decide when is a good time to run the clean up instead of an arbitrary timer / schedule.

Comment: Hi Mr Giggles welcome to S.F. Running `kubectl --v=3 top nodes` and its `top pod` friend will show exactly which APIs kubectl is invoking to get that answer. If you give the Pod's ServiceAccount a ClusterRoleBinding (and RoleBinding?) that allows it access to those same resources, I would expect it could get the same results at will

Comment: What do you mean by "service which can clean up another service"? What is the meaning of the "service" in your example? Could clarify it - add some example of "cleaning up service"? Which Kubernetes version are you using? Are you using some cloud provider solution or bare-metal?